# C# MVC - Html.RenderPartial("_somePartial", Model) vs Html.RenderPartial("_somePartial") - performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have question on **difference between performance using** `Html.RenderPartial("_somePartial", Model)` vs `Html.RenderPartial("_somePartial")` inside Index.cshtml file. In first case **we pass model** into each partial view. In second case **we don't specify which model we pass**. I understand that by default partial view uses parent view model.

##### Questions

1. Is there any performance difference between using first way vs using second way of using partials?
2. Is passing model into partial view faster way for rendering partials? Or is there no difference?
3. Does the partial view, which is without passed model, have to look for parent model by reference? Is this slower or is there no difference?

##### Example 1

In first case we pass model into partial view. For example if partial views are structured like this and in all cases we pass specific model to it.

Index.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModel.SomeModel
<div>
  @{Html.RenderPartial("_somePartial", Model);}
</div>
```

_somePartial.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModel.SomeModel
<div>
  @{Html.RenderPartial("_anotherPartialInsidePartial", Model);}
</div>
```

_anotherPartialInsidePartial.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModel.SomeModel
// and some code below
// ...
```

##### Example 2

In second case we don't pass model into partial view.

Index.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModel.SomeModel
<div>
  @{Html.RenderPartial("_somePartial");}
</div>
```

_somePartial.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModel.SomeModel
<div>
  @{Html.RenderPartial("_anotherPartialInsidePartial");}
</div>
```

_anotherPartialInsidePartial.cshtml:

```
@model ViewModel.SomeModel
// and some code below
// ...
```

Comment: I bet the performance difference is totally insignificant.

Comment: Can you measure the difference and report back?